# php regex 2 cases

Tags: php, regex

Is there any way in regex to match 2 cases
i got this file for example

```
bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$1
bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$0
bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$0
bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$0
bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$0
bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$0
bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$0
bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$1
```

I want to match it
with `bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa` at start
And `1` at end

Comment: If you mean start/end of LINE and not of file, please specify so in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After op edited his question, i think i understand what he needs to do:

```
    <?php


    $str = "
    bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$1
    bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$0
    bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$0
    bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$0
    bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$0
    bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$0
    bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$0
    bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$Bahaa$-$WTB$-$CH$-$11$-$Glavie$-$None$-$SOS$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$1";

    preg_match_all('/^bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa(.*?)1$/im', $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
```

example output:

> Array (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$-$-$-$11$-$-$-$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28
>   09:15:02$-$1
>               [1] => bfcb918c5343aaaf2100856c992aa6aa$-$-$-$-$11$-$-$-$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28
>   09:15:02$-$1
>           )
>
> ```
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => $-$-$-$-$11$-$-$-$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$
>         [1] => $-$-$-$-$11$-$-$-$-$1Mil$-$2012-01-28 09:15:02$-$
>     )
> ```
>
> )